# What solutions for a local server "migration"?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, mamp

I should deploy a xampp based web application (handling just some sql transactions), but my customer asked me to use it on his local machine (NOT my development machine).
Now, I cannot access my customer's machine, so I was wondering if there is a way to deploy a web app in my local server (xampp or similar, I need apache+sql+php5) and then "export" as an all in one folder containing my server, my db and my application logic.

Sorry if my request could seem a little strange, but it's the absolute first time someone asks me something like that job.

Any idea? Even not based on xampp: I just need to "migrate" a local webserver (including with db and logics) from my machine to another one in the easier way possible.

Thanks

Comment: Is your customer going to take full responsibility for maintaining the environment this application runs in or are they going to phone you all the time with problems? This is really a last resort. Once you hand over the code you lose control over your application, anything could happen to it. What was the original plan? To use a hosting service?

Comment: One option is to create a virtual machine (e.g. a VirtualBox "appliance"), make your stuff work on it and hand it over to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of migration here should refer to "creating another" server running with the "cloned" environment as your development server.

It simply involves installing MySQL, PHP and Apache to your customer's machine, do a FULL `mysqldump` of your app's database (which would include triggers, events, stored procedures, etc) and set up the app on the customer's newly installed server.

Setting up the app might just be by copying the app's source code into the new server's app directory. This is where php's `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is useful and saves you a lot of "relative" resolutions of file names.

If you made modifications to the `php.ini` file, which should have been avoid actually, you should also export those settings [of course by hand]. It is better to alter settings for the app from the app code itself by doing a `ini_set` call or using `.htaccess`

Most "php setup scripts" just do copy operations and set runtime variables, set paths, and some other functions that make the "host" environment "comfortable" for the app.

Answer (score -2):

just hand over the sourcecode, mysql dump and example php.ini en my.cnf to your client... It depends on his setup wether it works, but at least he will have all the resources to get it working.